# Change mtime within Python of a broken symlink

Tags: python, linux, macos, posix, symlink

Apparently there is nothing like `os.lutime` which would allow to change `mtime` of the symlink itself, even if the file it points to is absent. For that purpose on Linux and on OSX, `touch` command has `-h` option to not dereference the link.  But I found no way to do it natively cross-platform (at least on OSX and Linux) within Python.  So is there a remedy for my desire? ;)

Answer (score 0):

While not easy to make cross-platform, it is possible to use the `ctypes` module to call the native functions to do this.

Here is the Python 2 code I created to do this on macOS. I imagine with some tweaking it could be made to work on Linux also.

```
import ctypes
import ctypes.util

class ctype_timeval(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('tv_sec', ctypes.c_long),
        ('tv_usec', ctypes.c_long)
    ]

ctype_libsystemc = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(ctypes.util.find_library('libsystem.c'))
ctype_libsystemc_lutimes = ctype_libsystemc.lutimes
ctype_libsystemc_lutimes.restype = ctypes.c_int
ctype_libsystemc_lutimes.argtypes = [ctypes.c_char_p, ctype_timeval * 2]

def lutime(filename, time):
    times = (ctype_timeval * 2)()
    # access:
    times[0].tv_sec = time[0]
    times[0].tv_usec = 0
    # modification:
    times[1].tv_sec = time[1]
    times[1].tv_usec = 0

    return ctype_libsystemc_lutimes(filename, times)
```

You can use it just like you would `os.utime`:

```
lutime('file-or-symlink', (1488079452, 1488079452))
```